# Outlook/VBA - find UID in Subject and run search for UID in Mail items

Tags: vba, search, outlook, unique, identifier

I've been in and out of so many Microsoft docs and forums SEARCHING for the answer, I figured I'd just ask.

Long story short - I want to write a macro that, with an email highlighted in the main/mail pane in Outlook ...

1. Searches the subject line of the email for the case number/UID (always a four digit year, hyphen, and a six digit number, e.g., 2019-012345); and then
2. runs a basic search (not Advanced Find) in my inbox and all subfolders for any email with that UID in the subject line or body.

I'd offer a jumping off point but Outlook doesn't have a record macro function.

Functionally speaking ... my Outlook search option is set to include results from all folders.  I hit Ctrl-E and type in the UID and hit enter to search.  Would love to reduce that to one key stroke

Does the code have to get into DASL and MAPI?  The extent of my VBA knowledge goes to user forms and template letters so ... I'm in way over my head.